# How do I use a TransactionScope with two databases when one is SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, transactionscope, msdtc

I have two databases: dbGlobal is `SQL Server 2008`, and dbLocal is `SQL Server 2008 CE`.  For business reasons, I need to keep some data local to a user while other data global to all users.  In many cases, I'll have a table in dbLocal that has a column which references a table in dcGlobal.  In my C# code, I will want to have certain database operations happen within a transaction.

I've read that a single `TransactionScope` object can handle two database connections.  I think this may not be the case if one of those two database connections connects to a SQL Server CE instance.  Is this true?  Here's my code:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (DataContext dcGlobal = new DataContext(Program.dbGlobal), 
        dcLocal = new DataContext(Program.dbLocal))
    {
        ITable<tblDbGlobal> tblGlobal = dcGlobal.GetTable<tblDbGlobal>();
        ITable<tblDbLocal> tblLocal = dcLocal.GetTable<tblDbLocal>();

        //Invalid Operation Exception here
        var join = from tGlobal in tblGlobal.ToList()
                    join tLocal in tblLocal.ToList() on 
                        tGlobal.PkDbGlobal equals tLocal.FkDbGlobal
                    select new { tGlobal.Name, tLocal.Gender };

        foreach (var item in join)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", item.Name, item.Gender));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get an `Invalid Operation Exception` with the message "The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope." at the `var join ...` line.

While dcLocal runs on localhost, dcGlobal runs on a different computer on the network.  I double-checked that MS DTC (Distributed Transaction Controller) is running on both computers, and I ensured that the security settings were set up to allow almost anything.  I've also got my windows firewall turned off on both computers.

I tried using the [DTCPing](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2868) tool but I'm getting a couple of errors with that.  If I type in the full computer name of each computer to the other's DTCPing program, nothing happens.  I neither get a success nor failure message.  I can click on the *PING* button all day.

How can I set up a transaction for these two databases?

*I realize that I probably don't need a transaction scope for a select query.  I'm just using this as an example.  I will have more complicated queries that involve inserts, updates, and deletes that should happen within a transaction that can span two databases.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Distributed transaction with SQL Server Compact http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896149.aspx